# Using a noun as an adverb

Tags: parts-of-speech

I'm wondering how common, in English, it is to use a noun as an adverb. For example, *they were Christmas shopping; they were break dancing*. In those cases, 'Christmas' and 'break' are actually nouns defined in dictionaries.

I haven't encountered much like the cases above so far. Is it common in English? Are there more examples? Are there rules or something that can identify what kind of nouns that can be used as an adverb?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to mean "noun-adverb"?

Comment: @Kentaro I don't quite understand what you really mean.

Comment: I mean, "dancing", "shopping" are all nouns.

Comment: @Kentaro But they are used as verbs in those sentences, “They were Christmas shopping.” Don't they?

Comment: I also mean, infinite verb + ing can be mostly the noun link [ https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/ing-forms ]. I was taught when I was a 8th grader.

Comment: No, here the "shopping" is a noun.

Comment: @Kentaro, I'm confused more now, because what you are telling me contradicts the answers I got from this post: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230099/what-part-of-speech-is-christmas-in-who-were-christmas-shopping

Comment: I think and am afraid you'd better ask native speakers. I am not a native, but this should be the very basic grammar even to the non natives. Have a good day^^.

Comment: @Kentaro, The reason I asked is that noun used as an adverb is quite unusual to me. So far, I haven't seen it's been addressed in any grammar book. So, I'd like to go into deep about it.

Comment: I think it comes to the point that a non native speaker is "teaching" to a native speaker. But I thank you for arousing a naive question.

Comment: @Kentaro, Well, non native speakers often asked naïve questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with the analysis of these words as "nouns used as adverbs".

"Break-dancing" is a compound noun. There is a compound verb "he break-dances", but I would not consider "break" to be an adverb in that phrase. It is part of the verb.

Also "Christmas shopping" uses "Christmas" as an attributive noun (which are very common in English) to modify th  the noun "shopping. It may be possible to work backwards and form "He Christmas shops", but that would be odd. And then I would parse it as a compound verb, not "adverb+verb". You couldn't, for example say:
"Christmas he shops", or "He shops in London Christmas". If Christmas was an adverb, both of those could be correct.

So generally nouns don't get used as adverbs.  There are some cases in which a noun is used attributively with an -ing word  (such as "bird-watching") and it might be possible to form a compound verb (From karate-fighting to "he karate-fights") but this doesn't mean that the noun is acting as an adverb.

This doesn't prevent some words being both nouns and adverbs. For example

> He will shop in London tomorrow.  (tomorrow is an adverb)
>
> Tomorrow is another day.  (tomorrow is a noun)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it common in English?

They are fairly common. By that, I mean if you use such terms, you won't get a lot of raised eyebrows.

> Are there more examples?

Collins lists ["break dancing"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-dancing) (with a space) as a **noun**. It also has it without the space. Collins also lists ["Christmas shopping"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/christmas-shopping) as a noun.

Then there are these: [bird-watching](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bird-watching), [whale watching](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whale-watching), [binge drinking](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/binge-drinking), [binge eating](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/binge-eating), [skinny-dipping](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/skinny-dipping)

---

Note that the terminology or how you identify the modifier will depend on how you use the compound words in a sentence.

For example, in

> "They are Christmas shopping" and "I am bird watching right now"

both "Christmas" and "bird" are acting as adverbs modifying the verbs "shopping" and "watching" - these are present participles.

However, in

> "Are you done with you Christmas shopping" and "I love bird watching"

both "Christmas shopping" and "bird watching" are nouns.

In "shopping is fun"and "I enjoy shopping", "shopping" is a gerund. See [Is “shopping” a noun, verb or a gerund?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29333/is-shopping-a-noun-verb-or-a-gerund)

I think context is essential to understand what these sets of words are working as.

Note that I am not certain that this holds true for every example, as EddieKal mentions in their comment.

Comment: Yeah, but aren't they a noun adjective? Not **adverb**.

Comment: @Kentaro I agree. I would call _bird_, _Christmas_ attributive nouns in _bird-watching_ and _Christmas shopping_.

Comment: @EddieKal If we say "They are Christmas shopping" then "Christmas" is acting as an adverb modifying the present participle "shopping". But if we say "Are you done with you Christmas shopping" then the whole thing is a noun. That is my understanding. Is that right? In "I am bird watching right now" "bird" is acting as an adverb to the verb "watching", no? But in "I love bird watching" that whole thing is a noun.

Comment: @AIQ That is indeed where the line gets blurry. I am fairly certain this has been touched on in books such as CGEL and discussed on ELL and/or ELU, but I haven't put in the effort to find previous discussions. I would take "Christmas shopping" and "bird watching" as compound words, with _Christmas_ and _bird_ taking up attributive roles as nouns in their respective compound words. This is just my personal take on it.

Comment: If we consider other compound verbs, say, _babysit_, _house-hunt_, _brainwash_, _baby-proof/waterproof_, all of them share the **N + V** structure in common. _I can't come to the party. I am babysitting._ Is _baby_ really an adverbial modifier that tells us _how_ I am sitting?

Comment: @EddieKal I agree. So, until there is a better answer posted, can I add some bits from your comments to my answer?

Comment: @AIQ You are welcome to use anything from our discussion in your answer. But do take my words with a grain of salt. In the meantime I would suggest delving deeper into the ELU/ELL archives.

Comment: @AIQ >If we say "They are Christmas shopping" then "Christmas" is acting as an adverb modifying the present participle "shopping". I am sorry I am totally confused. There, the "shopping" is the noun.

Comment: @Kentaro In "They are eating", "eating" is a verb, right? Similarly, in "They are shopping", "shopping" is a verb too (present participle). See this [Is “shopping” a noun, verb or a gerund?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29333/is-shopping-a-noun-verb-or-a-gerund)

Comment: @AIQ No, it is a noun. As I commented. Your first "They are eating" is the "Present progressive tense" link [ https://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm ]

Comment: @kentaro Your link says this: "The present progressive tense indicates continuing action, something going on now. This tense is formed with the helping "to be" **verb**, in the present tense, plus the present participle of the **verb** (with an -ing ending): *"I am **buying** all my family's Christmas gifts early this year. She is **working** through the holiday break.*" In "I am shopping", "shopping" is a verb. In "Shopping is fun", "shopping" is a noun. This is mentioned in the answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: @AIQ So there could be no "noun **adverb**. We are here talking about the "adverb". Not the adjective nor the noun.

Comment: @Kentaro I think you are mixing it up with a gerund. In the link you posted for OP, the British Council link, they are talking about gerunds. *"A gerund is a form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun, in English ending in -ing, e.g., **asking** in "do you mind my **asking** you?." In "I like shopping", shopping is a gerund (noun).

Comment: @AIQ So you are answering yourself. Gerund or not, there is no **adverb** modifying nouns.

Comment: @Kentaro Do you see shopping is a noun in "they are shopping"?

Comment: @dan As the native speaker AIQ confirms, the answer is "no". To me it is not even a gerund, but it is the "present progressive".

Comment: @Kentaro If you take it as the form of present progressive of 'shop', why do you take issue with Christmas being an adverb to modify 'shopping' then?

Comment: @dan It is not an adverb! It is a noun adjective.