# Street smart: modify adjectives with nouns?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, compounds

I was confused by the roles of nouns in English. It seems that nouns can modify verbs as stated in [this qeustion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/277038/10484) and adjectives in these examples:

> Do You Know How to Be **Street** Smart?
> ... the prior predictive kernel distributions are not **orders of magnitude** different from the observed data.

Sources:

1. https://kidshealth.org/en/kids/street-smart.html
2. https://www.nature.com/articles/s43586-020-00001-2

I wonder if the two types of nouns act the same role? In the above sentence is `street` acting as an adverb? Or something else? When can we modify adjectives with nouns?

Comment: I think these are compounds, like the noun-verb compounds referred to in your other question. _Street smart_ = knowing how to look after yourself in public places. Other examples that occur to me are _book learned_ = having acquired one's knowledge from books, and _trigger happy_ = prone to firing guns irresponsibly.

Comment: "Street-smart" is a compound adjective, where the first base is a noun and the second an adjective. Note the hyphen.

Comment: You are making a common ELL mistake - thinking than an idiom reveals some hidden rule of grammar. It doesn’t. This is an idiom.

Comment: Well, I dunno, it may not be official but in many cases, like this one, it has a predictable "rule" of its own and will sound even more awkward to native speakers if it's done other than according to that rule.  But it's true that it's not a sign that the official rules of grammar allow for this, it's just defying them.

Answer (score 1):

> Do You Know How to Be Street Smart?

> Q. In the above sentence is street acting as an adverb? Or something else? When can we modify adjectives with nouns?

---

A.1 **Street-Smart is an adjective** and is the American translation of The UK's "streetwise" Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/street-smart?q=Street%20Smart)

A.2

> **Attributive Nouns** - A noun can also be used like an adjective to modify another noun. Ref [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/nouns.htm)

> For example: diamond ring; car door

> In these examples, the examples "diamond," and "car" are functioning like adjectives. When nouns are used like this, they're called "attributive nouns."

> **Compound Adjective** - A compound adjective is a single adjective made up of more than one word. The words in a compound adjective are usually grouped together using hyphens to show it is a single adjective. Ref [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_adjectives.htm)

> Here are some example of compound adjectives:

> four-foot table, 12-page magazine, free-range eggs, never-to-be-forgotten experience, well-deserved award

---